# Unwanted queries merge in Oracle 10g

Tags: sql, oracle

I am working on Oracle Database 10g Release 10.2.0.5.0. I have view like:

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW some_view
(
    A,
    B
)
AS
    SELECT A, B
    FROM table_a
    WHERE condition_a
UNION ALL
    SELECT A, B
    FROM table_b
    WHERE condition_b;
```

and some database function `some_db_package.foo()`. My problem is that when I execute query:

```sql
SELECT A, some_db_package.foo(B) val
FROM some_view
WHERE some_db_package.foo(B) = 0;
```

Oracle is merging conditions from query and `some_view`, so I am getting something like:

```sql
SELECT A, some_db_package.foo(B) val
FROM table_a
WHERE some_db_package.foo(B) = 0 AND condition_a
UNION ALL
SELECT A, some_db_package.foo(B) val
FROM table_b
WHERE some_db_package.foo(B) = 0 AND condition_b;
```

`some_db_package.foo()` executes on all rows from `table_a` and `table_b` and I would like to execute `some_db_package.foo()` only on filtered (by `condition_a` and `condition_b`) rows. Is there any way to do that (i.e. by changing sql query or `some_view` definition) assuming that I can not use optimizer hints in query?

---

Problem solved. Just to summmarize:

1. `some_db_package.foo()` - for given event and date range counts event's errors which occured between dates (foo() access tables), so it is deterministic only when `sysdate > dateTo`.
2. `select * from ( SELECT A, some_db_package.foo(B) val FROM some_view )` does not make difference.
3. Actually I do not need `UNION ALL` and I did test with `UNION`, but stil the same result.
4. `with some_view_set as (select A, B from some_view) select * from ( select A, some_db_package.foo(B) val from some_view_set ) where val = 0` does not make difference.
5. I did test with optimizer hints and unfortunately Oracle ignored them.
6. Using `ROWNUM >= 1` in `some_view` was the solution for my problem.

Thank you for help, I really appreciate it.

Comment: Why do you want/need to do that? Is your function call slowing down the query? Did you measure whether getting rid of the function calls will speed it up?

Comment: And why can you not use optimizer hints?

Comment: Yes, some_db_package.foo() is quiet expensive and this is why i want to filter table_a and table_b (both with large amount of rows) first. And I can not use optimizer hints, because DB admin in my company does not allow to do that.

Comment: What (roughly) does `some_db_package.foo()` do? Does it access tables? Can you declare it as [DETERMINISTIC](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e25519/create_function.htm#LNPLS1918)? If it's not deterministic could you utilise [scalar sub-query caching](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/issue-archive/2011/11-sep/o51asktom-453438.html)? (you could do both)

Comment: Secondly does selecting the result and _then_ filtering make a difference? i.e. `select * from ( SELECT A, some_db_package.foo(B) val
FROM some_view ) where val = 0`. Thirdly do you need a UNION ALL? Could you make this a UNION and try to force Oracle to do the unique sort first?

Comment: Another variant to try:  `with some_view_set as (select A, B from some_view) select * from ( select A, some_db_package.foo(B) val from some_view_set ) where val = 0`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`ROWNUM`](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/pseudocolumns009.htm#i1006297) is usually the best way to stop optimizer transformations.  Hints are difficult to get right - the syntax is weird and buggy and there are many potential transformations that need to be stopped.  There are other ways to re-write the query, but `ROWNUM` is generally the best way because it is documented to work this way.  `ROWNUM` has to evaluate last to be used in Top-N queries, you can always rely on it to prevent query blocks from being merged.

**Sample schema**

```
drop table table_a;
drop table table_b;

create table table_a(a number, b number);
create table table_b(a number, b number);

insert into table_a select level, level from dual connect by level <= 10;
insert into table_b select level, level from dual connect by level <= 10;

begin
    dbms_stats.gather_table_stats(user, 'table_a');
    dbms_stats.gather_table_stats(user, 'table_b');
end;
/

--FOO takes 1 second each time it is executed.
create or replace function foo(p_value number) return number is
begin
    dbms_lock.sleep(1);
    return 0;
end;
/

--BAR is fast, but the optimizer doesn't know it.
create or replace function bar(p_value number) return number is
begin
    return p_value;
end;
/

--This view returns 2 rows.
CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW some_view AS
    SELECT A, B
    FROM table_a
    WHERE a = bar(1)
UNION ALL
    SELECT A, B
    FROM table_b
    WHERE a = bar(2);
```

**Slow query**

This query takes 20 seconds to run, implying the function is evaluated 20 times.

```
SELECT A, foo(B) val
FROM some_view
WHERE foo(B) = 0;
```

The explain plan shows the conditions are merged, and it appears that the conditions are evaluated from left to right (but don't rely on this always being true!).

```
explain plan for
SELECT A, foo(B) val
FROM some_view
WHERE foo(B) = 0;

select * from table(dbms_xplan.display);


Plan hash value: 4139878329

---------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Id  | Operation           | Name      | Rows  | Bytes | Cost (%CPU)| Time     |
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|   0 | SELECT STATEMENT    |           |     1 |     6 |     5   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|   1 |  VIEW               | SOME_VIEW |     1 |     6 |     5   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|   2 |   UNION-ALL         |           |       |       |            |          |
|*  3 |    TABLE ACCESS FULL| TABLE_A   |     1 |     6 |     3   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|*  4 |    TABLE ACCESS FULL| TABLE_B   |     1 |     6 |     3   (0)| 00:00:01 |
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------

Predicate Information (identified by operation id):
---------------------------------------------------

   3 - filter("FOO"("B")=0 AND "A"="BAR"(1))
   4 - filter("FOO"("B")=0 AND "A"="BAR"(2))

Note
-----
   - automatic DOP: skipped because of IO calibrate statistics are missing
```

**Fast query**

Add a seemingly redundant `ROWNUM` predicate that does nothing except prevent transformations.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW some_view2 AS
    SELECT A, B
    FROM table_a
    WHERE a = bar(1)
    AND ROWNUM >= 1 --Prevent optimizer transformations, for performance.
UNION ALL
    SELECT A, B
    FROM table_b
    WHERE a = bar(2)
    AND ROWNUM >= 1 --Prevent optimizer transformations, for performance.
;
```

Now the query only takes 4 seconds, the function is only run 4 times.

```
SELECT A, foo(B) val
FROM some_view2
WHERE foo(B) = 0;
```

In the new explain plan it's clear that the `FOO` function is evaluated last, after most of the filtering is complete.

```
explain plan for
SELECT A, foo(B) val
FROM some_view2
WHERE foo(B) = 0;

select * from table(dbms_xplan.display);


Plan hash value: 4228269064

------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Id  | Operation             | Name       | Rows  | Bytes | Cost (%CPU)| Time     |
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|   0 | SELECT STATEMENT      |            |     2 |    52 |     6   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|*  1 |  VIEW                 | SOME_VIEW2 |     2 |    52 |     6   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|   2 |   UNION-ALL           |            |       |       |            |          |
|   3 |    COUNT              |            |       |       |            |          |
|*  4 |     FILTER            |            |       |       |            |          |
|*  5 |      TABLE ACCESS FULL| TABLE_A    |     1 |     6 |     3   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|   6 |    COUNT              |            |       |       |            |          |
|*  7 |     FILTER            |            |       |       |            |          |
|*  8 |      TABLE ACCESS FULL| TABLE_B    |     1 |     6 |     3   (0)| 00:00:01 |
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

Predicate Information (identified by operation id):
---------------------------------------------------

   1 - filter("FOO"("B")=0)
   4 - filter(ROWNUM>=1)
   5 - filter("A"="BAR"(1))
   7 - filter(ROWNUM>=1)
   8 - filter("A"="BAR"(2))

Note
-----
   - automatic DOP: skipped because of IO calibrate statistics are missing
```

Ben's idea to make the function `DETERMINISTIC` may also help reduce the function calls.